# CSS animation not being delayed and resetting after animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, fade

Basically I need to use CSS animations to make 3 lines of text fade in one by one (without JavaScript or other CSS modules)

Here is the faulty code I have written to do this:

```css
body{background-color: black;}

.text-zone{
  position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 35%;
  width: 50%;
    max-height: 90%;
}

.text{
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 53px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

#delayedText1 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fade1;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

#delayedText2 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fade2;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

#delayedText3 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fade3;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes fade1 {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fade2 {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fade3 {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="text-zone">
  <div class="text">
    <h1 id="delayedText1">Hi,</h1>
    <h1 id="delayedText2">I'm Faizan,</h1>
    <h1 id="delayedText3">web developer.</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, when this runs, The page is blank for one second, then all of the text fades in all at once, and disappears after a second. This is my first time using CSS animations so this is probably a simple issue. Please can someone explain to me what has gone wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using the _same_ animation-delay for all three elements, when you want the animations to start at different times (meaning, with _different delays_) …?

Comment: Oh, I just tried that and now the animation happen one by one but the text disappears after the animation.

Comment: And if you want to perform the same animation function on all three elements, then you don’t need three differently named animations that all do the exact same thing, _one_ is enough.

Comment: _“but the text disappears after the animation”_ - go look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#delayedText1 { opacity: 0; animation-name: fade1; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 3s; } #delayedText2 { opacity: 0; animation-name: fade2; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 6s; } #delayedText3 { opacity: 0; animation-name: fade3; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 9s; }

Same code as you typed here,you should combine it inside your script and it will work perfectly
Goodluck